# How to find mongo documents with no duplicates values for a given field

Tags: mongodb

Given this dataset:

```
db.mycollection.insert([
  {a:1, b:2, c:3},
  {a:1, b:3, c:4},
  {a:0, b:1, c:3},
  {a:3, b:2, c:4}
])
```

I need a way to list all documents that doesnt have duplicates values for, let say, the field "a".

So it need to return:

```
[{a:0, b:1, c:3}, {a:3, b:2, c:4}]
```

Comment: You could try to group the values by `a` (to get a mapping of `a` to list of entries with the according `a`) and then remove the entries from the mapping where the size of the value-list is greater 1/retain only the entries where the size of the value-list is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the desired result. The aggregation pipeline would look like this:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
   {
       "$group": {
           "_id": "a",
           "data": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
           "count": { "$sum": 1 }
       }
   },
   {
       "$match": { "count": 1 }
   },
   {
       "$project": {
           "_id": 0, "a": "$data.a", "b": "$data.b", "c": "$data.c" 
       }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending my comment above, first group the result by `a` and add a `count`, then filter the entries with `count` 1:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
  {
    $group : { _id : "$a", "count" : { $sum : 1 }, entries : { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
  },
  {
    "$match" : { "count" : 1 }
  }
])
```