# find mongo documents while ignoring duplicate values mongo side

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

(Question inspired by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506289/how-to-find-mongo-documents-with-no-duplicates-values-for-a-given-field))

Given a dataset :

```
db.mycollection.insert([
  {a:1, b:2, c:3},
  {a:1, b:3, c:4},
  {a:0, b:1, c:3},
  {a:3, b:2, c:4}
  {a:4, b:1, c:4}
])
```

I want to find for given values of a key (say a should be between 0 and 3 included) one and *only one* document, and ignore subsequent finds for that value, ie if a document with a value 1 for a has already been found, the search should not return any document with 1 as value for the a key anymore. The order of the findings could be determined by the value of another key.

In our example, the expected output will be :

```
# Findings are sorted by value of the b key
[{a:0, b:1, c:3}, {a:3, b:2, c:4}, {a:1, b:2, c:3}]
```

Here is a the code that I worked on, I then had to drop the duplicates from my side instead of mongo side.

```
import pymongo, pandas

result = dict(db.mycollection.find({'a': {'$in': [i for i in range(4)]}}).sort('b', pymongo.ASCENDING))

print(result)
>>> [{a:0, b:1, c:3}, {a:3, b:2, c:4}, {a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:1, b:3, c:4}]
```

Since I work with a collection potentially containing millions of documents, I would need the 'ignore duplicates' part to be done on mongo side, saving both memory and data transit time.

Comment: Sort on key b followed by group on a and pick first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment by Veeram:

```
l = [i for i in range(4)]

result = db.mycollection.aggregate([{'$sort': {'b': 1}},
                           {'$group': {
                              '_id': '$a',
                              'data': {'$first': '$$ROOT'}
                                      }
                            },
                            {'$match': {'_id': {'$in': l}}}])

result_list = [i['data'] for i in result]

print(result_list) # Omitted the ObjectId that should appear too
>>>[{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 4},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 3}]
```

This seem to work for me, you just have to notice that your result will not necessarily be sorted by the 'b' key since it iterates over the 'a' key before looking at the order of 'b'.